# Why I cannot fetch all the users who likes post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why do I get this error? I do have 'last_signed_in_at' column in users table for sure.

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'last_signed_in_at' in 'order clause'

My codes are

**controller**

```
@users = @post.likes
```

**view**

```
<% @users.order("last_signed_in_at DESC").limit(3).each do |user| %>
    <li>
        <%= user.profile.nickname %>
        <%= user.last_active_at %>    
    </li>
<% end %>
```

**<%= debug(@users) %>**

```
[#<ActsAsVotable::Vote id: 2, votable_id: 4, votable_type: "Post", voter_id: 1, voter_type: "User", vote_flag: true, created_at: "2012-12-22 13:30:37", updated_at: "2013-01-01 18:55:51">, 
 #<ActsAsVotable::Vote id: 7, votable_id: 4, votable_type: "Post", voter_id: 2, voter_type: "User", vote_flag: true, created_at: "2012-12-23 14:47:04", updated_at: "2013-01-02 00:36:48">]
```

Comment: You sure? It doesn't look like it based on the error message.

Comment: if you remove the order() clause does it work?  Or are you possibly confusing last_signed_in_at and last_active_at?

Comment: @Jason If I remove it, now it shows this error **undefined method `profile'**

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: @cat You'll need to give more detail on your data structure, otherwise we'll just be guessing what post/user/profile/... look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scope ActsAsVotable::Vote, but somehow waiting for User :)

Controller:

```
@users = User.where(:id => @post.likes.map(&:voter_id)).order("last_signed_in_at DESC").limit(3)
```

View:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
```